# Oracle PL/SQL Return in Blocks

Tags: oracle, plsql

Just a question since I can't seem to find the answer somewhere else.

So I got an PL/SQL function which contains a nested block, and within the 2nd level block it got a return value of 1. Does this mean that it will not proceed to the next block and return the value 1 or it will only terminate the current block?

Thanks!

Sample structure for illustration:

```
FUNCTION EXAMPLE ( sample_variable VARCHAR2)
    RETURN NUMBER
IS
    BEGIN 
       BEGIN
          /*CODES HERE*/
       EXCEPTION
           WHEN OTHERS THEN
           RETURN 1; //HERE IS THE QUESTION. WHEN I GOT HERE IN RETURN DOES IT TERMINATE THE WHOLE 
                     //FUNCTION AND RETURN 1 OR IT WILL STILL CONTINUE TO BLOCK 2*/
       END;
       BEGIN /*BLOCK 2*/
          /*OTHER CODES HERE*/
          RETURN 2;
       END;
    END
 END EXAMPLE;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terminates the whole `function`.

From oracle [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/return_statement.htm#LNPLS01340):

> In a function, the RETURN statement assigns a specified value to the
>   function identifier and **returns control to the invoker**, where
>   execution resumes immediately after the invocation.